# How to apply language correctly?

Tags: android

I'm working multi languages on android 2.2. I change language in onCreate of every activities like this:

```
  Locale locale = new Locale("nl");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Of course i put these code before calling setContentView and adding  android:configChanges="locale" into manifest. But when the launcher activity displayed at the first time there are some words change to my desired language correctly but some words stay in English. The other activities (not launcher activity) changed language is OK. And when i switch back to launcher activity from the other activities, it now changed all words to my desired language correctly. I don't know why the first time of launcher there are some words in launcher activity not change to my desired language correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i found a solution that solved my problem completely. I figured out that the locale is reset automatically by system (or whatever has an ability of changing locale), that why i set the default locale but it worked not correctly. Here is my solution, you should create a class that extend Application, then override the method as below:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Locale locale = new Locale(YourDesired_langCode);
    newConfig.locale = locale;
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

So every time the default locale is reset out side of your app, this method is called and it will reset default locale again with your desired language. Now it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you make it more simple ?

You could just create different language-values directories in your app 
(res/values-en, res/values-fr, res/values-nl, et... ) in which you will store the languages values associated to a string key.

So once your directory "values-en" is created, right click on it, add an Android xml Values File, name it language.xml, then click next, then select the configuration "Language" in the left panel of the displayed screen" then click finish.

Then in this recently created file, create all the key-values for each string you want to be translated. Then once it's done, copy your language.xml file in another other values-xx directory, and change the values of all your strings.

So , your language.xml file in values-en will contain :

```
<string name="hello">Hello</string>
```

And the language.xml file in values-fr will be :

```
<string name="hello">Bonjour</string>
```

Then to get these string values in your activities, juste call

String helloString = getResources().getString(R.String.hello);

The application will automatically load the right String resources depending on the device language configuration

Comment: Yes, i knew that and i had resource folders for all my supported languages for sure.Because i want to change language within my app itself, so it's a bit more complicated.